# Renaming a file in Git Bash on Windows

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I'm new to Git and Linux/Bash. I have Git Bash installed on Windows 10. How do I rename a file using an absolute path?

For instance the Windows folder path is:

```
D:\GitHub\Datsville\datsville_inlined
```

The old file name is:

```
datsville_rev493_inlined_n_boxed_f.xmpd
```

The new file name is:

```
datsville_sf_rev493_inlined_n_boxed_f.xmpd
```

Bonus: How do I put multiple such commands in a script file? Thanks.

Comment: Use `mv` like you would do in Linux.

Comment: Is Git Bash case sensitive?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just as Linux.

Comment: I am new to Linux so this is very hard for me.

Comment: Read the documentation of [`git mv`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv). It renames the files on disk then it updates its index. This is the easiest (and the right) way to do it, no matter the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a git repository, you can use [`git mv`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18667308/6547185) for renaming/moving files, but only within the same repository. Also avoid doing this on a folder which has been created using `git submodule`.

Another option is to create a bash script for [rename/move files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35338907/6547185) and then [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) thay again to the repo. Alternatively, you can do this using windows `cmd` or create a batch file, just add path to `git.exe` to the `path` environment variable, if you haven't already done so.

Also, since you are new to using git, I recommend that you use TortoiseGit - this should help you understand what git is.

Answer (score 7):

**In Linux, the commands are case sensitive.**

`mv` is the command you're looking for. It's the shorten for "move", but you can rename files. Like `mv oldfilename newfilename`. I think the main problem is that you can't access files on the `C:`, `D:` etc. drive. Linux has a different directory structure than Windows. There is a **root directory** (`/`), and everything else is **mounted** to a sub-directory. Like you can access your pendrive on `/mnt/pendrive` (just an example, does not work). On Git Bash, the Windows drives are mounted to `/c`, `/d` etc. So it you want to rename it, you can do like this:

```sh
mv /c/somepath/oldfilename /c/somepath/newfilename
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not use git bash but if you want to use the linux "rename" command you can download Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) 2 here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

Answer (score 0):

using command: git mv oldfilename newfilename.
once done, you will see file renamed in "git status" output.

Answer (score -1):

### Use `mv` command in windows

As mentioned in above answer, `mv` command can be used in windows as well to rename the filename. I tried `rename` and `ren` commands s suggested, but I was getting error: `bash: ren: command not found`.

Use below to change the filename:

`mv filename new_filename`